# React: loop through array response does not work

Tags: reactjs, express, get, axios

I run an axios get request to an Express server to get some dummy data:

```
  customers = [
    { id: 1, firstName: "John" },
    { id: 2, firstName: "Brad" },
    { id: 3, firstName: "Mary" }
  ];
```

the data that is returned is determined by a user input: if the user enters "Brad", the result being returned will be { id: 2, firstName: "Brad" }.

For some reason, when I loop through the data returned, nothing works. Looking into the React Chrome Extension, the State returned is as follows:

```
{
  "firstName": "Brad",
  "id": 0,
  "customers": [],
  "res": []
}
```

Because I am learning React, I will post the whole component for you to see, perhaps the problem is something I don't see yet as a newbie:

```
    class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      id: 0,
      customers: []
    };


      this.getName = this.getName.bind(this);

  }

     onChange = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value });
     };

    getName = e => {
     e.preventDefault();
     axios
      .get("/api/customers", {
        params: {
          firstName: this.state.firstName
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({ res: this.state.customers });
      });
     };

     componentDidMount() {}

     render() {


     //if (!this.state.customers.length) return "Data not available yet";
      return (
       <div>
        <h2>Customers</h2>
        <div className="card card-body mb-4 p-4">
          <div className="h1 display-4 text-center">
            <h1 className="i fas">Search for a customer</h1>
            <p className="lead text-center">Get the Customer's Name Here</p>
            <form onSubmit={this.getName}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  placeholder="customer name ..."
                  name="firstName"
                  value={this.state.firstName}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary btn-lg-block mb-5"
                type="submit"
              >
                Get Customer
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is where I loop throuhg the data:

```
        {this.state.customers.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.firstName}</li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the Express route I'm calling:

```
app.get("/api/customers", (req, res) => {
  let { firstName } = req.query;
  const customers = [
    { id: 1, firstName: "John" },
    { id: 2, firstName: "Brad" },
    { id: 3, firstName: "Mary" }
  ];
  console.log("the customer's name is " + firstName);
  var str = customers.filter(x => x.firstName == firstName);
  res.json(str);

});
```

So What I want is to display the data in a  element below the input bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
this.setState({ customers : res });
```

instead of :

```
this.setState({ res: this.state.customers });
```

Also, try to use React Hooks in order to refactor your code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint David. Your solution didn't work for me but it pointed me into the right direction. I changed the line into: this.setState({ customers: res.data }); and it works. I am accepting your answer though. For React hooks, I'm not there yet.